# AWS Access Key ID failed on hadoop fs -cp command

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services

I was trying to run the hadoop fs -cp command but got the following error message:

-cp: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively)

I'm new to hadoop and s3 so can anyone please give advice on what I should do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please [refer](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3) .

go to

1. cd ${HADOOP_HOME}/conf/hadoop-site.xml and add/update

   ```
   <property>
   <name>fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId</name>
   <value>Your AWS ACCESS KEY</value>
   </property>

   <property>
   <name>fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
   <value>Your AWS Secret Access Key</value>
   </property>
   ```